# Apache Tomcat Interconnectivity

Tags: java, web-services, apache, tomcat, load-balancing

I have following requirement . Please provide me some help on this thanks in Advance.

Software : - 
1.Unix
2.apache 2.0
3.tomcat 6.0.35

Current scenario : -
1.MOD_JK to connect Apache and tomcat
2.Tomcat has multiple web services running as multiple Apps
3.Apache is running as load balancing.
3.There will be multiple Tomcat.

Requirement : - 
1. There are web service which require to connect to multiple app through webservices which is running inside same tomcat.So the requirement is how to make App inside tomcat to connect Web servies inside same tomcat without going to load balancer.
2.I want to hide the context path of some App how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Add another HTTP connector listening on 127.0.0.1 and just route traffic to it.

Doesn't sound like a particularly tidy design though.